# Achievements tab shows awarded badge but the link is not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, achievements-dialog

I just earned the Yearling badge in Meta Super User. The message prompted in my Achievements tab correctly, only that there is no link in the text.

> [image]

Shouldn't there be a *working* link to my profile or somewhere else?

Comment: Actually there is an `<a>`, it's the parent of the snippet you included. There's no `href` set while other items do have the attribute set.

Comment: Well, in fact the problem is not about the `<a>` itself, but about the text not driving me anywhere.

Comment: I realise that's not your point, but that's no reason to ignore technical inaccuracies. It was also with that one answer in mind (which is now deleted).

Comment: Fair enough. Just deleted the reference to `<a>`.

Comment: I see it too. We just removed a line that implied (incorrectly) that it'd link to your profile, and doing so may have broken some of the links. (My taxonomy, which goes to the tag page, still works, but most others don't.)

Comment: @Jaydles Hmm. I don't think it should be related to that change (or at least not in an obvious way), but I'll take a closer look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Jay was right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224529/achievements-tab-shows-awarded-badge-but-the-link-is-not-working#comment733138_224529) - this was a side-effect of yesterday's change that removed the "See your profile" link from the badge notifications. (But don't tell him I said that.)

This left some badges without any links at all, so they ended up... well... unlinked.

Starting with the next build, we'll show "See your profile." again for these link-less badges.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having this same issue, ***I just noticed it today***. There is no href attribute for those that are not working. I never remember clicking on a new message/achievement and it not taking me anywhere. So is this a bug? Or did you decide to remove href's if it would take you to your badges under your profile?

[image]

Comment: Exactly! Your image is way more explicit than mine :)